# Can't figure out how to reassign an element in a list of lists in this Python code

Tags: python, nested-lists

I understand that how accessing elements in a list of lists usually works. I know that if you have a list `L = [['a', 'b'], ['c', d'],['e', 'f']]`, you can access 'a' using `L[0][0]`. Still, I'm not sure why the same thing isn't working in the following battleship game code:

```
from random import randint
from random import choice

# make a 5x5 board
board = []
row = ['O']*5
for x in range(5):
    board.append(row)

def print_board():
    for item in board:
        print ' '.join(item)

#check if input falls within 5x5 grid
def check_valid(guess_row, guess_column):
    return guess_row in range(5) and guess_column in range(5)
#return True- is valid choice, return False- not valid choice

#check that the input hasn't been guessed previously
def check_repeat(guess_row, guess_column):
    return board[guess_row][guess_column] != 'O'
#return True- repeat, reurn False- new

#check if input is a correct answer
def check_correct(guess_row, guess_column):
    return (guess_row, guess_column) == (row1, col1) or (guess_row, guess_column) == (row2, col2)
#return True- is correct, return False- is not correct

#place a 2-position ship
while True:
    #pick random place to start
    row1 = randint(0,4)
    col1 = randint(0,4)
    #choose adjacent second position
    move_direction = choice(['north', 'south', 'east', 'west'])
    if move_direction == 'north':
        row2 = row1 - 1
        col2 = col1
    elif move_direction == 'south':
        row2 = row1 + 1
        col2 = col1
    elif move_direction == 'east':
        row2 = row1
        col2 = col1 + 1
    else: # must be west 
        row2 = row1
        col2 = col1 - 1
    #check that the second position is valid, else pick new values
    if row2 in range(5) and col2 in range(5):
        break
positions_left = 2 #how many points player needs to hit
#you now have a ship at coordinates (row1, col1), (row2, col2)

turns = 5

#the gameflow itself:
print 'let\'s play battleship!'
while turns > 0:
    print 'You have %i turns remaining.' % turns
    print_board()
    guess_row = int(raw_input('Guess a row: ')) - 1 #-1 to account for python 0-indexing
    guess_column = int(raw_input('Guess a column: ')) - 1

    if check_valid(guess_row, guess_column) == False:
        print 'Sorry, those aren\'t valid coordinates'
    else: #continue game if valid
        turns -= 1
        if check_repeat(guess_row, guess_column): #old guess
            print 'You seem to have guessed that already.'
            turns += 1 #don't count this turn
        elif check_correct(guess_row, guess_column):
            print 'Hit!'
            board[guess_row][guess_column] = '!'
            positions_left -= 1
            if positions_left == 0:
                'You sunk the battleship!'
                turns = 0 #stops game
            else:
                print 'You can sink this ship in %i more hits!' % positions_left
        else:
            board[guess_row][guess_column] = 'X'
            print 'Sorry, you missed!'
```

The problem occurs where after evaluating the player's guess, I try to reassign the 'O' to either '!' (indicating a hit) or 'X' (indicating a miss). This should happen at:

```
  elif check_correct(guess_row, guess_column):
                print 'Hit!'
                board[guess_row][guess_column] = '!'
```

and at:

```
    else:
        board[guess_row][guess_column] = 'X'
        print 'Sorry, you missed!'
```

Instead, what happens is the entire column ends up being reassigned to that value. So when a player guesses row 1, column 1, that guess is interpreted as `guess_row = 0, guess_column = 0`. 
I expect the new value of board then to turn into:

```
[['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],['O', 'O', 'O', 'O',
'O'],['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

Instead it becomes:

```
[['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],['X', 'O', 'O', 'O',
'O'],['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],['X', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']]
```

It's really bizarre because when I pull out small fragments of the code and try to do just this thing, it works fine, but I don't see what I'm missing when I try to do it as part of the whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding same `row` variable at each iteration into your board. You should add a new row instead as follows:

```
board = []
for _ in range(5):
    board.append(['O'] * 5)
```

Comment: thanks that seemed to work!
Not sure I understand why though... why does it matter which method you use to make the original board? No matter how the board has been constructed, shouldn't changing the values in it later on work the same way?

Comment: Because what you created is basically a list of 5 references pointing to same variable named `row`, *in other words, you don't have 5 different rows, you have one row added 5 times into a board*, so when you make a change in one of them, all others will get affected as they all are references to same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
row = ['O']*5
for x in range(5):
    board.append(row)
```

As a result of the above board will contain 5 references to row, i.e. the same list. Thus change one subsist, will change all file. You need to make copies of row, e.g.

```
for x in range(5):
    board.append(row[:])
```

Hope this helps.